# Tradução da mensagem de bloqueio temporário

Tags: bug, suporte, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Após um usuário reportar que sua conta foi bloqueada de fazer perguntas por um determinado tempo. O curioso da situação foi que todo o texto explicando o porque estava em inglês, acabei traduzindo/adaptando ele.

Comment: @Math, coloquei como resposta :P pq fiquei com medo da pergunta ser descontextualizado pq é uma resposta xD rsrss

Comment: É que você demorou uns 5 min pra postar a resposta, daí seu texto estava bem estranho a princípio, mas agora faz mais sentido :)

Comment: Adicionei o texto original inteiro (a screenshot tava cortada) e a versão que foi pro ar. Recomendo a tradução do [Meta post em Inglês](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days/271543#271543)

Comment: @Gabe Qual o URL da página que mostra essa mensagem?

Answer (score 7):

## `TEXTO ORIGINAL`

**It looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back soon!**

You've asked `NumQuestions` questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account from asking questions entirely.

It's been `DaysSinceLastQuestion` days since you asked your last question. We ask that you wait `CalculatedLimit` days before asking again. Use this time to revisit [your previous questions](/users/current?tab=questions), editing to address any issues that folks have pointed out in comments.

**Recommended reading:**

- [tips on asking great questions](/help/how-to-ask) as well as our guidance on
- [which questions are allowed here](/help/on-topic)

**Additional advice**

- Examining highly-scored questions in the tags that interest you is a great way to study how to ask better questions, that also get better answers much sooner!
- We don’t demand perfection, but ***please* make sure you use proper grammar, spelling and capitalization**, it really helps!
- Improve downvoted questions rather than deleting them.
- Do not delete your account, create new accounts, or otherwise attempt to circumvent these restrictions.
- Do not contact us regarding these restrictions, they cannot be lifted.

Failure to heed this advice may increase the severity of these restrictions.

**For more information**

See: [Why won’t the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days/271543#271543)

It sometimes takes a few attempts at a good question in order to fully learn how our system works, and what the community expects from folks seeking answers. Just **do your best** to make sure you've improved the quality of your existing questions, and we'll see you in `CalculatedLimit` days!

---

## `TEXTO TRADUZIDO`

**Parece que você precisa de uma pausa – tome um fôlego e volte em breve!**

Você fez `NumPerguntas` perguntas recentemente, algumas das quais não foram bem recebidas pela comunidade. Cada pessoa aprende no seu próprio ritmo, e é normal cometer alguns erros. No entanto, a recepção das suas questões até agora não foi boa, e isso pode bloquear sua conta permanentemente de fazer perguntas.

Faz `DiasDesdeUltimaPergunta` dias que você fez sua última pergunta. Nós pedimos que você aguarde `LimiteCalculado` dias antes de fazer uma nova questão. Use esse tempo para revisar [suas questões anteriores](/users/current?tab=questions) e editá-las para resolver os problemas apontados pelos usuários nos comentários.

**Leitura recomendada:**

- [Dicas de como fazer boas perguntas](/help/how-to-ask) e nosso guia sobre
- [Quais questões são permitidas no Stack Overflow](/help/on-topic)

**Conselhos adicionais**

- Examine questões com pontuações altas nas quais você tem interesse; essa é uma boa maneira de estudar como elaborar perguntas melhores e assim conseguir respostas melhores rapidamente.
- Nós não exigimos perfeição, mas por favor tenha certeza de usar corretamente a gramática, ortografia e capitalização, pois isso faz diferença na clareza do texto.
- Prefira melhorar as questões que levaram votos negativos do que apagá-las.
- Não delete sua conta e não crie novas contas para burlar esta restrição.
- Não entre em contato conosco sobre essas restrições, pois elas não podem ser canceladas manualmente.

Ignorar esses conselhos pode acarretar em restrições mais sérias.

**Para mais informações:**

Leia: [Why won’t the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days/271543#271543)

É muito difícil acertar tudo de primeira. Costuma levar algum tempo até que você entenda como o sistema funciona e o que esperamos de quem faz as perguntas, de forma a fazer boas perguntas. **Faça o melhor possível** para aumentar a qualidade das suas perguntas já existentes e nos vemos em `LimiteCalculado` dias!