# Eleições para Moderador 2015 - Questionário

Tags: debate, eleição

Essa é a sessão de perguntas e respostas para os candidatos à moderador do Stack Overflow em Português. As perguntas enviadas [uma semana atrás](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3886/12) estão listadas aqui, para que os candidatos possam respondê-las. Nem todas as perguntas enviadas estão no questionário final, apenas as 8 mais bem votadas, além de duas perguntas pré-determinadas.

Os candidatos devem responder esse post, listando cada pergunta do questionário e a sua resposta. Para ajudar, as perguntas estão pré-formatadas como citações e com espaço entre elas, para sua resposta. Basta copiar tudo [depois da linha divisória](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/680ad81e-97ee-4291-8404-22ab4dfe9c40/view-source). Lembrem-se também de colocar seu nome no **topo** do seu post, para que todo mundo possa saber quem é *antes* de ler tudo que você escreveu.

Depois que todos responderem, esse tópico será um registro das ideias e propostas de cada candidato e vai aparecer na perfil de cada um na página da eleição.

Boa sorte!

---

> 1. Por que você precisa dos poderes de moderador ♦ para fazer o que você propôs em sua candidatura?
> 2. Como você vê a qualidade das perguntas e respostas do site hoje? Enquanto moderador, como pretende atuar para manter a qualidade (se achar que está satisfatória), ou melhorá-la (se achar que isso é necessário)?
> 3. Qual é o período de tempo que você pretende moderar diariamente?
> 4. Uma pergunta é feita e recebe algumas respostas muito boas, o *AP* sinaliza a pergunta e pede para que ela seja *excluída*, pois pode-lhe causar problemas no local onde ele estuda ou no trabalho.
>      O que você faz?
> 5. Todos os dias chegam novos usuários no site postando perguntas. Como são inexperientes, muitas destas perguntas têm problemas e acabam fechadas e/ou recebendo votos contrários. Que tipo de atitudes você costuma ou pretende tomar com novos usuários que enquanto bem-intencionados, postam perguntas de má qualidade?
> 6. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?
> 7. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?
> 8. Um novo usuário posta uma pergunta extremamente confusa, rapidamente fechada pela comunidade, após alguns comentários explicando a ele o problema. O usuário, furioso, reclama no Meta, dizendo que aqui tem regras demais, que somos uns babacas filhos-duma-égua, mandando todo mundo pra aquele lugar. Como você reagiria?
> 9. Caso eleito, você pretende aumentar sua participação no Meta ou você já a considera satisfatória?
>      Caso sua resposta seja que vai aumentá-la, por favor explique por que esperar se tornar um moderador para começar a interagir com a comunidade sobre as questões que definem os rumos do site? Por que já não o fez desde sempre?
>      Caso sua resposta seja que já a considera satisfatória, por favor justifique. Se possível, com exemplos de sua participação que considera que merecem destaque.
> 10. Qual/quais *soft skills*¹ você possui que são fundamentais para um moderador do SOPt?
>       <sup>¹*soft skills*: conjunto de atributos e/ou competências que promovem boas relações com as pessoas</sup>

Comment: Mas é para editar a pergunta ou criar uma resposta para cada um?

Comment: @jorgeb cada um numa resposta

Comment: *Lembrem-se também de colocar seu nome no topo do seu post, para que todo mundo possa saber quem é antes de ler tudo que você escreveu.* Isso é uma faca de dois gumes; às vezes a leitura e tomada de posição podem ser mais neutras se você não souber desde o início quem é o autor das respostas.

Comment: "*Depois que todos responderem, esse tópico será um registro das ideias e propostas de cada candidato e vai aparecer na perfil de cada um na página da eleição.*" - Se algum candidato não responder, como é que fica? Se algum candidato responder somente após o término das primárias, como é que fica?

Comment: @Gabe dá para excluir a resposta apagada? A página aqui diz "4 respostas" mas na verdade a 4 não devia ter sido aceite pelo sistema...

Comment: @Sergio Diz 4 respostas só para quem tem 10000 ou mais de reputação. Saudades dos meus privilégios do beta... O que ela tem de tão grave para ter que excluir de fato ao invés de apenas ficar invisível para os 99%+ de usuários que não tem reputação suficiente para vê-la?

Comment: @VictorStafusa o problema é que é uma resposta de um _não candidato_.  Não devia ter sido aceite pelo sistema. A tí aparece-te 3 ou 4 respostas aqui na página?

Comment: @Sergio Para mim aparece 3. Só deve aparecer 4 para quem tiver mais do que 10000 de reputação.

Comment: @VictorStafusa ah, ok, nesse caso é deixar ficar e alguém na SE registe isso no _TODO_ list para evitar que aconteça de novo. Btw: já não te falta muito para os 10mil, esses poderes já voltam...

Comment: @Sergio Na verdade, isto daqui é um tópico normal no meta sem nada de especial no banco de dados ou na engine do SE. Talvez o que seria necessário é alguma coisa que mostrasse "3 Respostas (+1 Excluída)" ao invés de "4 Respostas", sempre que alguma das respostas excluídas fosse visualizável. E também alguma opção para ocultar da tela as excluídas. Mas isso daí já é algo para postar lá no metão, pois afeta toda a rede StackExchange, e não apenas este tópico.

Comment: @VictorStafusa assim faz mais sentido. Pensei que esta página era uma daquelas em "modo especial" como a da eleição que esconde votação negativa. Bom esclarecimento! ++

Comment: @VictorStafusa A participação no questionário (assim como qualquer debate eleitoral) não é obrigatória. É, sim, do interesse de todos os candidatos responder às perguntas da melhor maneira possível. Quem não responder, faz sob sua própria conta e risco.

Comment: @Gabe Sim, mas neste caso, nada vai ser exibido no perfil do candidato na página da eleição?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Sim

Comment: @Gabe Nesta eleição (2016) não vai ter um questionário como esse?

Comment: @VictorStafusa estava pensando nisso agora, pelo que vi, a [coleção de perguntas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3886/3117) deveria ter sido criada desde o ínicio, e esse questionário viria ao ar ao fim da etapa das candidaturas, se não estou enganado. Agora não dá mais tempo de fazer a coleção de perguntas, o máximo que poderia fazer é reaproveitar as perguntas do ano passado e mandar ao ar agora, que já acabou a primeira fase.

Answer (score 19):

## Respostas do [Math](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3117/math)

> 1. Por que você precisa dos poderes de moderador ♦ para fazer o que você propôs em sua candidatura?

De acordo com a [Teoria da Moderação](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), os moderadores devem intervir pouco com seus poderes de diamante (♦), pois essas ações têm efeito imediato e poderosos, que se sobrepõe às ações dos demais usuários. O fato desses poderes deverem ser pouco usados é que a comunidade já tem mecanismos de moderação excelentes, então as ações dos moderadores devem servir para corrigir pontos excepcionais em que a ação tomada pela comunidade na verdade vão contra a vontade da maioria. Elas devem ser muito bem pensadas pois também servirão de exemplo para todos os membros da comunidade.

Hoje eu já sou muito ativo nas atividades de moderações do site que são possíveis ser atingidas através dos pontos de reputação, além de estar em sintonia com a cultura da comunidade e sempre participativo nas tomadas de decisões que decidem o rumo dela. É por esses motivos que eu me julgo apto a ir mais além para tratar também as sinalizações e também me tornar um representante da vontade de todos.

Meu desejo em me tornar moderador, na verdade vai da minha vontade de retribuir para a comunidade tudo aquilo que me ajudou a me tornar o profissional que sou hoje. Pois como candidato a moderador, estou oferecendo voluntariamente o meu esforço e dedicação para que a comunidade seja exatamente do jeito que seus usuários desejam que ela seja. O que eu terei em benefício próprio é a satisfação e o reconhecimento.

> 2. Como você vê a qualidade das perguntas e respostas do site hoje? Enquanto moderador, como pretende atuar para manter a qualidade (se achar que está satisfatória), ou melhorá-la (se achar que isso é necessário)?

Vejo que a maioria das perguntas estão satisfatórias. Quando surge alguma fora do padrão que existe na comunidade, esta logo age de acordo para que a adequá-la.

Além disso, a página do SOPT na Area 51 mostra que os indíces estão dentro dentro do considerado aceitável:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em minha interpretação, os índices da porcentagem de perguntas respondidas e quantidade de respostas por pergunta que estão um pouco baixos, indicam um leve grau de perguntas de baixa qualidade que poderiam ser tratadas, e que devemos estar sempre atentos para não deixar esse índice piorar.

E como bem sabemos, sempre é possível melhorar, para que isso ocorra, pretendo levar para o Meta situações em que acho que podem servir de exemplo para que a comunidade possa dar sua opinião através de respostas, comentários e votos, revelando qual é a decisão da comunidade e guiando a todos como atuar no futuro.

> 3. Qual é o período de tempo que você pretende moderar diariamente?

O período de atuação como moderador dependende da demanda, então a minha resposta será que atuarei sempre quando necessário, desde que eu esteja online.

Já o período que eu fico online, durante a semana é basicamente por todo o tempo do meu expediente, desde que eu não esteja em reunião ou resolvendo algo que não pode sofrer interrupções (mas isso não ocorre com muita frequência), e eventualmente a noite.

Durante o fim de semana varia muito, caso eu esteja viajando ou por qualquer outro motivo longe do meu computador eu acesso o site através do celular ou tablet para ver o que está acontecendo e analisar itens da fila de análise. Quando estou em casa posso ser mais atuante. Mas o fato é que no geral, a grande demanda de serviço é justamente durante o horário de expediente, onde estou constantemente presente.

> 4. Uma pergunta é feita e recebe algumas respostas muito boas, o AP sinaliza a pergunta e pede para que ela seja excluída, pois pode-lhe causar problemas no local onde ele estuda ou no trabalho.
>      O que você faz?

Em casos de informações sensitivas, o que eu poderia fazer é verificar uma forma de alterá-las por informações genéricas sem manter o seu histórico.

Ao contribuir com o site, o usuário está concordando com a licença "cc by-sa 3.0", que garante a propriedade das publicações à empresa Stack Exchange. Essa licença dá o direito de compartilhar as informações e até mesmo adaptá-las (sempre citando a fonte) mas não lhe garante o direito de excluí-las. É claro que sob algumas circunstâncias algumas publicações acabam sendo excluídas, portanto, o principal motivo para mantê-las no ar, como em casos que elas possuas respostas e votos a favor é de se imaginar que ela é útil para a comunidade, portanto, não seria justo tanto para quem gastou seu tempo respondendo como quem poderia usufruir dessa informação ficar sem ela.

> 5. Todos os dias chegam novos usuários no site postando perguntas. Como são inexperientes, muitas destas perguntas têm problemas e acabam fechadas e/ou recebendo votos contrários. Que tipo de atitudes você costuma ou pretende tomar com novos usuários que enquanto bem-intencionados, postam perguntas de má qualidade?

Quando existe um problema pontual na pergunta de um novato eu conserto ou eu explico através dos comentários o que pode ser melhorado. Em todo caso eu costumo também sempre sugerir a leitura do [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e do guia [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), mas vejo que isso na maioria dos casos é insuficiente, pois pouquíssimos lêem. Muitas vezes o conjunto dessas ações não são o suficiente para que o usuário se interesse em melhorar sua pergunta, nesse caso não há muito o que fazer, e a pergunta deve se manter fechada.

Acredito que o principal é sempre ser cordial e respeitoso em especial com os novatos, pois uma palavra mal colocada pode espantá-los para sempre do site por ainda não entenderem como aqui funciona, e acabarem achando que o ambiente aqui é naturalmente hostil, quando na verdade todos sabemos que não é.

> 6. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?

Conversaria com ele a cada oportunidade que surgisse, geralmente em público mesmo, caso isso não fosse muito expositório. Se isso não for possível ou a conversa em público não resolver, seria a hora de de repente ter uma conversa mais de canto com ele, lhe relembrando a cultura do site e a maneira que a comunidade espera dos usuários. O tamanho da sua contribuição pro site não deve ser motivo para que ele tenha regalias de burlar as regras e as boas maneiras da comunidade.

Se for um problema grave de desrespeito e a conversa não resolver, seria a hora de colocá-lo no cantinho da reflexão por alguns dias para ele repensar suas atitudes. Não adianta ficar babando ovo de um usuário que contribui bastante mas que incomoda e espanta outros usuários, essa não é a definição verdadeira do que é uma comunidade.

> 7. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

Falaria com ele até que chegássemos a um acordo e pudéssemos tomar a devida ação de forma que os dois ficassem satisfeitos, outros usuários e outros moderadores também estariam livres para dar sua opinião. No geral, não vejo motivos para que isso seja tratado de forma particular, por que geralmente é do interesse de todos.

Se for um problema cuja sua natureza seja que não termos certeza de como a comunidade prefere agir, levantaríamos o assunto no Meta de forma impessoal, para não expor ninguém negativamente, e deixando claro que o assunto em questão ainda não havia sido levantado e merece a opinião dos demais usuários do site.

> 8. Um novo usuário posta uma pergunta extremamente confusa, rapidamente fechada pela comunidade, após alguns comentários explicando a ele o problema. O usuário, furioso, reclama no Meta, dizendo que aqui tem regras demais, que somos uns babacas filhos-duma-égua, mandando todo mundo pra aquele lugar. Como você reagiria?

Primeiramente deve-se contar até 10 :)

Em seguida, dar uma analisada na publicação que ele criou no Meta e remover as palavras ofensivas, se após removê-las ainda restarem palavras na publicação que consigam formar uma pergunta é hora de respondê-la, explicando o por quê de sermos como somos.

Se a ofensa for muito grande e ficar claro que na verdade o usuário não está aqui para papo, é melhor poupar a todos de um *stress* desnecessário e encerrar a discussão aí mesmo, excluindo publicações e banindo o usuário.

O histórico mostra que geralmente a conversa não tem adiantado de muita coisa, e no final das contas é possível que todas suas publicações: pergunta no Meta, os comentários ofensivos e possivelmente até a pergunta no site principal (por falta de qualidade), sejam removidas. Mas não é por que ainda não temos um caso de sucesso que não devemos tentar explicar para os usuários mais esquentados como é a nossa cultura, com jeitinho um dia a gente descobre uma fórmula que nos permitirá a partir de então catequizar com sucesso os próximos hereges que visitarem mas se recusam a aceitar a cultura do site.

> 9. Caso eleito, você pretende aumentar sua participação no Meta ou você já a considera satisfatória?
>      Caso sua resposta seja que vai aumentá-la, por favor explique por que esperar se tornar um moderador para começar a interagir com a comunidade sobre as questões que definem os rumos do site? Por que já não o fez desde sempre?
>      Caso sua resposta seja que já a considera satisfatória, por favor justifique. Se possível, com exemplos de sua partipação que considera que merecem destaque.

Considero que minha participação já é satisfatória, não pretendo aumentá-la nem diminuí-la, sendo eleito ou não.

A razão de considerá-la satisfatória se deve ao fato de eu sempre estar presente nas principais decisões que ajudaram a determinar os rumos do site, sendo essa presença marcada perguntando, respondendo, comentando ou votando. Além disso mantive um ritmo de participação relativamente constante, desde os primeiros dias da minha inscrição no site.

Como destaque, gostaria de constatar o fato de eu estar bem rankeado, tanto como perguntador como respondedor nas principais tags, que são [`debate`](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/debate/topusers), [`bug`](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bug/topusers) e [`suporte`](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/suporte/topusers), e também no [ranking de participação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users).

> 10. Qual/quais *soft skills*¹ você possui que são fundamentais para um moderador do SOPt?
>       <sup>¹*soft skills*: conjunto de atributos e/ou competências que promovem boas relações com as pessoas</sup>

Sou extremamente calmo (e pareço mais ainda por trás de um teclado e um monitor) e acredito que consigo me colocar no lugar das pessoas para entender como elas se sentem. Por esses dois motivos considero poder ser um bom resolvedor de conflitos.

Meu primeiro cadastro na rede StackExchange foi no StackOverflow versão em Inglês, então toda vez que eu quero me por na pele de um novato, eu fecho os olhos e puxo na memória como foi meu início naquele site, e daí eu penso como que eu gostaria que tivessem me tratado e assim eu trato as pessoas aqui. Eu também já fui novato aqui, mas lá eu fui novato por muito mais tempo, lá eu tive que editar muitas publicações para conseguir atingir os 50 pontos de reputação e poder começar a comentar, que foi a partir de então que eu comecei a me sentir confiante para participar mais ativamente do site. Esse tipo de situação que eu adoraria evitar por aqui.

Answer (score 17):

## Respostas do [bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto)

> 1. Por que você precisa dos poderes de moderador ♦ para fazer o que você propôs em sua candidatura?

Depois 1 ano moderando o site, percebi que o melhor das ferramentas de moderador ♦ não são os superpoderes de intervenção (fechar ou excluir conteúdos com 1 clique). Na verdade, esses poderes às vezes são até um fardo. As melhores ferramentas são as de análise do site: buscar conteúdos excluídos, ver comentários excluídos, ver estatísticas detalhadas das filas de análise, ver os motivos pelos quais as publicações são sinalizadas, entre outros. Outra ferramenta importantíssima é a sala de chat dos moderadores. Lá é o único chat onde se fala mais sobre o site do que sobre qualquer outro assunto, ao contrário do que ocorre no [estouro de pilha](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).

Essas ferramentas me permitem formar uma visão bem mais completa da dinâmica do site, e ajudam a ter uma percepção melhor da comunidade: como os usuários pensam, para onde a comunidade caminha. Se eu deixar de ser moderador, é desses poderes que sentirei mais falta, pois sem eles eu teria uma visão mais parcial/pessoal do site. Consequentemente, minha participação (no meta, e nos comentários de orientação aos usuários) provavelmente ficaria prejudicada.

> 2. Como você vê a qualidade das perguntas e respostas do site hoje? Enquanto moderador, como pretende atuar para manter a qualidade (se achar que está satisfatória), ou melhorá-la (se achar que isso é necessário)?

Não fui atrás de números para sustentar isso, mas tenho a impressão de que a quantidade de perguntas e respostas de quem não entende o funcionamento do site tem aumentado bastante. Basicamente, trata-se de perguntas e repostas com tom de diálogo ou bate-papo. Tendem a ser curtas e incompletas, com alta dependência de links externos ou fortemente baseadas em opiniões. Como moderador, quero buscar uma maneira mais eficiente de orientar esses usuários e convencê-los que "o formato do site" é outro, e que é outro porque esse outro é vantajoso. Só que não é vantajoso para essas pessoas, pelo menos não imediatamente. Por isso, é uma tarefa dura. E por isso eu disse "buscar uma maneira mais eficiente de orientar". Isso é algo que a nova equipe de moderação vai precisar debater, e, em conjunto, procurar alguma solução melhor que o tradicional comentário com link para o tour. Talvez elaborar algum outro material de referência simples e objetivo que seja complementar ao tour.

> 3. Qual é o período de tempo que você pretende moderar diariamente?

Como eu disse na minha candidatura, menos do que o tempo que dedico hoje. Na prática, isso significa que vou continuar acessando o site várias vezes ao dia, principalmente à tarde e à noite. Mas provavelmente vou concentrar o trabalho de tratamento de sinalizações em uma hora por dia. Durante os finais de semana, devo concentrar o tratamento de sinalizações no domingo à noite.

> 4. Uma pergunta é feita e recebe algumas respostas muito boas, o *AP* sinaliza a pergunta e pede para que ela seja *excluída*, pois pode-lhe causar problemas no local onde ele estuda ou no trabalho. O que você faz?

Depende um pouco de como o AP fez o pedido, mas a regra geral é evitar a exclusão de conteúdos que possam ser úteis para outras pessoas. Na maioria dos casos, é possível editar a pergunta para remover os dados sensíveis, e pedir aos gerentes de comunidades que excluam do banco de dados as revisões anteriores, de modo que esses dados sumam também do histórico de edição. Assim ninguém sai prejudicado, nem o AP, nem a comunidade.

> 5. Todos os dias chegam novos usuários no site postando perguntas. Como são inexperientes, muitas destas perguntas têm problemas e acabam fechadas e/ou recebendo votos contrários. Que tipo de atitudes você costuma ou pretende tomar com novos usuários que enquanto bem-intencionados, postam perguntas de má qualidade?

Já falei sobre esse assunto na pergunta 2 acima. A primeira medida é sempre deixar comentários orientando os novatos. Um trabalho paralelo é ajudar a comunidade a entender que é possível não "metralhar" os novatos (pelo menos não imediatamente depois de postarem) e ao mesmo tempo garantir a qualidade do site. Mas sempre haverá novatos que discordam desse ponto de vista, não entendem as orientações, e/ou se sentem ofendidos. E sempre haverá usuários mais experientes que preferem expressar suas opiniões com votos contra e de fechamento, sem deixar comentários orientando ninguém. Todos têm o direito de agir dessa maneira se quiserem, e nesses casos resta aos moderadores lidar com eventuais agressões que podem ocorrer nessas situações.

> 6. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?

Vai depender da gravidade das discussões e da frequência. O primeiro passo é limpar as discussões nos comentários. O segundo é entrar em contato com o usuário por mensagem privada (que ele recebe pelo site e por e-mail), deixando claro que esse tipo de comportamento é nocivo e não é tolerado. O terceiro passo são suspensões progressivas (aumentando o período de suspensão em caso de reincidência). Mas não existe uma fórmula sobre como agir, cada caso é um caso. Se um usuário chega a ser advertido ou suspenso, depois passa meses com "bom comportamento", e depois acaba causando uma discussão, ele não será imediatamente suspenso a menos que tenha sido realmente ofensivo nessa discussão. Num caso desses, pode-se apenas excluir os comentários, ou tratar do assunto por mensagem privada ou até numa sala de chat privada.

> 7. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

Eu falaria com ele, com os demais moderadores e com o Gabe, no chat dos moderadores. Posso acabar convencido de que eu estava errado. Ou o outro lado pode se convencer de que estava errado. Caso ninguém mude ideia, prevalece a posição com mais apoiadores. A opinião da comunidade também pesa na decisão final, caso o debate tenha sido levado ao meta (por um terceiro, pois de maneira alguma um moderador deve lavar roupa suja no meta em vez de conversar com os colegas).

<sup>Adendo após leitura da resposta do Sergio: claro que discordâncias públicas entre moderadores podem ocorrer de maneira natural e educada; geralmente, aliás, são benéficas. O que eu nunca farei é reverter a ação de outro moderador sem falar com ele antes, a menos que ele esteja incomunicável ou que seja óbvio que cometeu um erro que precise ser reparado imediatamente. Quando falei sobre "lavar roupa suja", tinha em mente os casos que é melhor tratar em particular.</sup>

> 8. Um novo usuário posta uma pergunta extremamente confusa, rapidamente fechada pela comunidade, após alguns comentários explicando a ele o problema. O usuário, furioso, reclama no Meta, dizendo que aqui tem regras demais, que somos uns babacas filhos-duma-égua, mandando todo mundo pra aquele lugar. Como você reagiria?

É o que eu disse na pergunta 5: sempre haverá quem reaja dessa maneira. Partindo do princípio que a comunidade agiu corretamente, o máximo que podemos fazer é  explicar as ações da comunidade, com toda a educação. Se isso não adiantar, é melhor ficar calado (*não alimente os trolls*). Se o usuário passar dos limites e se tornar muito agressivo, ele pode ser suspenso.

> 9. Caso eleito, você pretende aumentar sua participação no Meta ou você já a considera satisfatória?
>      Caso sua resposta seja que vai aumentá-la, por favor explique por que esperar se tornar um moderador para começar a interagir com a comunidade sobre as questões que definem os rumos do site? Por que já não o fez desde sempre?
>      Caso sua resposta seja que já a considera satisfatória, por favor justifique. Se possível, com exemplos de sua partipação que considera que merecem destaque.

Eu considero a minha participação satisfatória, e sou um dos usuários que mais participaram no meta (no momento, tenho [234 respostas e 82 perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto)). Eu particularmente gosto das minhas tentativas de convencer a comunidade a mudar certos comportamentos, como em *[Sem comentários](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2002/sem-coment%C3%A1rios)*, e das tentativas de orientar novos usuários, como *[Oh, não! Editaram minha pergunta!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2212/oh-n%C3%A3o-editaram-minha-pergunta)* e *[O Stack Overflow em Português é um fórum?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/o-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-%C3%A9-um-f%C3%B3rum)* – mesmo não considerando essas tentativas propriamente bem-sucedidas.

> 10. Qual/quais *soft skills*¹ você possui que são fundamentais para um moderador do SOPt?
>       <sup>¹*soft skills*: conjunto de atributos e/ou competências que promovem boas relações com as pessoas</sup>

- Gentileza, diplomacia e paciência.
- Mente aberta para ouvir e respeitar as opiniões dos outros, mesmo quando diametralmente opostas às minhas.
- Capacidade de perceber quando é melhor me calar. Essa eu desenvolvi enquanto moderador, e continuo tentando melhorar nesse ponto. Muitas vezes, a melhor resposta é o silêncio.

Comment: "Muitas vezes, a melhor resposta é o silêncio" tantas vezes faço isso no dia a dia. Resulta a maioria das vezes quando o assunto começa a descambar.

Comment: "247 perguntas e 84 respostas", o correto não seria "234 respostas e 82 perguntas"? Como conseguiu embaralhar tanto esses números? Hehehe

Comment: @Math Eu sou moderador, as minhas contagens incluem itens excluídos e não me dei conta :)

Comment: Ok, somado ao fato de que você inverteu perguntas com respostas :)

Comment: Muita coisa pra escrever e nenhum tempo pra revisar dá nisso, @Math

Answer (score 13):

## Respostas do [Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio)

> 1. Por que você precisa dos poderes de moderador ♦ para fazer o que você propôs em sua candidatura?

Existem casos práticos no dia a dia do site em que ter mais poderes faz a diferênça. Para além de possiveis sinalizadores que só moderadores têm acesso, algumas perguntas precisam de uma ação rápida. Ou porque precisam de ajuda, ou porque precisam de ser fechadas antes que fiquem cheias de respostas despistadas a tentar adivinhar o que a pergunta quer, ou porque o AP precisa de ajuda.

Muitas vezes visito perguntas cujo problema verdadeiro (e muitas vezes a própria resposta) estão espalhadas por comentários que não acabam. Acho isso prejudicial ao site e como moderador poderei ajudar a limpar e organizar, mas também posso deixar um comentário a pedir para AP e AR ajudarem a organizar.

Acho que certos comentários vindo de um moderador são acatados de maneira diferente.

Devo dizer contudo que vou tentar contribuir ainda mais para a comunidade participar. Se um moderador fizer tudo a comunidade fica como filhos mimados que sabem que o papá e a mamã vão limpar e torna-se passiva.

> 2. Como você vê a qualidade das perguntas e respostas do site hoje? Enquanto moderador, como pretende atuar para manter a qualidade (se achar que está satisfatória), ou melhorá-la (se achar que isso é necessário)?

Acho que há muitas perguntas que não são claras e respostas que são demasiado curtas. Não tenho nada contra respostas curtas e acho que em alguns casos pode assumir-se que o AP deve ter conhecimento de conceitos básicos que não precisam de explicação. Ainda assim acho que podemos de modo geral explicar um pouco melhor.

Vou comentar e incentivar a melhorias.

> 3. Qual é o período de tempo que você pretende moderar diariamente?

Irá variar de dia para dia. Tenho visitado o site todos os dias desde que ele nasceu. Eu estou por cá e quero ajudar. Uns dias passo 4 horas no site outros meia hora. Vontade não falta de ajudar, farei o que puder.

> 4. Uma pergunta é feita e recebe algumas respostas muito boas, o *AP* sinaliza a pergunta e pede para que ela seja *excluída*, pois pode-lhe causar problemas no local onde ele estuda ou no trabalho.
>      O que você faz?

Analizo com ele possibilidades de alterar a pergunta de maneira a que ele ou a empresa não sejam reconhecidos, sem tirar o sentido à pergunta. Se foi útil para ele e tem boas respostas então será util para outros. Esse é o motivo principal do site. Em casos excepcionais consultarei os outros moderadores.

> 5. Todos os dias chegam novos usuários no site postando perguntas. Como são inexperientes, muitas destas perguntas têm problemas e acabam fechadas e/ou recebendo votos contrários. Que tipo de atitudes você costuma ou pretende tomar com novos usuários que enquanto bem-intencionados, postam perguntas de má qualidade?

Eu reajo muitas vezes a chuva de votos negativos em usuários novos. Reparei que um comentário a dizer "bemvindo ao Stackoverflow" faz para essa chuva e muda a atitude de muitos pois apercebem-se de que se trata de um novo membro. Acho que em muitos casos é importante fechar a pergunta rápido e convidar o AP a explicar melhor. Acho que ter um membro de prestigio da comunidade a dizer "olá" quando se chega a um novo site é sempre muito positivo. Como moderador tentarei dar exemplo de boas maneiras.

> 6. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?

É importante sentirmos que somos uma comunidade. Estar a dizer mal do vizinho não faz o meu dia ser melhor. Essa mensagem tem de ser compreendida. Vou elogiar as boas respostas e apontar o que eu acho que pode melhorar. Na resposta ou no tratamento/contacto com outros membros da comunidade. Há regras e limites que têm de ser respeitadas de preferência sem super-poderes.

> 7. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

Eu consigo aceitar opiniões diferentes. Em casos de desacordo extremo posto no Meta. Mas tudo farei para que tais decisões sejam tomadas por voto democrático dentro do trio de moderação. Ninguém ganha com um moderador a postar no Meta que está em desacordo com outro moderador. Acho que pelo diálogo entre moderadores a se chega a um consenso.

> 8. Um novo usuário posta uma pergunta extremamente confusa, rapidamente fechada pela comunidade, após alguns comentários explicando a ele o problema. O usuário, furioso, reclama no Meta, dizendo que aqui tem regras demais, que somos uns babacas filhos-duma-égua, mandando todo mundo pra aquele lugar. Como você reagiria?

Se uma pessoa se dá ao trabalho de ir ao Meta e escrever um post isso já é positivo. Eu irei tentar transformar essa energia em sinergia. Tentar fazer-lhe compreender que se os comboios saíssem da estação à hora que quisessem na pista que quisessem a coisa não ia funcionar muito bem... 
Eu ouví dizer quando era criança que "não há mais cego que aquele que não quer vêr", vou tentar que ele veja o potencial que há nesta comunidade e como ele pode benefeciar e fazer parte dela.

> 9. Caso eleito, você pretende aumentar sua participação no Meta ou você já a considera satisfatória?
>      Caso sua resposta seja que vai aumentá-la, por favor explique por que esperar se tornar um moderador para começar a interagir com a comunidade sobre as questões que definem os rumos do site? Por que já não o fez desde sempre?
>      Caso sua resposta seja que já a considera satisfatória, por favor justifique. Se possível, com exemplos de sua partipação que considera que merecem destaque.

Eu gostava de ter ainda mais tempo para participar no Meta. Houve um periodo em que me afastei do Meta por sentir que a comunidade não era ouvida pela SE, aí foquei-me mais em ajudar as pessoas que faziam perguntas e a quem de facto ajudava com algo concreto. Creio que depois destas eleições vou visitar mais o Meta, independentemente de ser moderador ou não. Sinto que as eleições são um passo decisivo para sentir que somos nós que escolhemos os cargos de prestígio da comunidade. Como moderador talvez visite ainda mais o Meta, mas em deterimento de responder a perguntas que também gosto. Se não vou mais ao Meta é principalmente por falta de tempo. Acho o papel do Meta fundamental para nos podermos chamar comunidade.

> 10. Qual/quais *soft skills*¹ você possui que são fundamentais para um moderador do SOPt?
>       <sup>¹*soft skills*: conjunto de atributos e/ou competências que promovem boas relações com as pessoas</sup>

Na minha vida profissional sempre trabalhei com pessoas, grupos pequenos e grandes. Na minha vida privada cresci numa familia onde havia personalidades fortes que muitas vezes enravam em conflito umas com as outras. Aprendí vendo de fora o que é uma bulha desnecessária e aprendí também a entrar de mansinho numa bulha para acalmar os ânimos. Mais tarde na vida tive papeis de dirigente no trabalho e isso ensinou-me a ser claro e direto no meu discurso.

Answer (score 11):

## Respostas do [utluiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/227/utluiz)

> 1. Por que você precisa dos poderes de moderador ♦ para fazer o que você propôs em sua candidatura?

Se eleito, continuarei usando o poder de moderador para:

- Salvar questões suspensas, mas que poderiam ser reabertas com alguma ação mais elaborada e que não obtiveram a devida atenção da comunidade.
- Manter a ordem no site, revertendo ações indevidas de usuários ou limpar "ruídos" tais como comentários obsoletos, ofensivos ou desnecessários.
- Analisar comportamento suspeito que ocorrem esporadicamente para determinar se existem usuários usando a ferramenta de forma equivocada ou até mal intencionada, tal como manter várias contas.
- Dar um "empurrãozinho" em questões onde obviamente uma ação precisa ser tomada, sem que seja necessário passar por todo o processo de sinalização e fila de análise.

A lista continua, mas é bem verdade que, independente de se ter ou não super poderes, continuarei ajudando a comunidade de uma forma ou de outra.

Sei que sempre poderei contar com a boa vontade dos colegas e futuros moderadores, podendo chamar a atenção deles pelo chat ou meta.

> 2. Como você vê a qualidade das perguntas e respostas do site hoje? Enquanto moderador, como pretende atuar para manter a qualidade (se achar que está satisfatória), ou melhorá-la (se achar que isso é necessário)?

A qualidade do site tem melhorado bastante. Vejo muitas pessoas novas entrando e aprendendo rapidamente como o site funciona e como as questões e respostas devem ser formuladas. Isto é muito positivo.

Por outro lado, com as novas pessoas sempre haverá ocasiões em que perguntas e respostas com baixa qualidade serão postadas.

Como moderador, pretendo focar mais em orientar esses novos usuários através de comentários.

Tenho feito isso evitando um pouco comentários enlatados, escrevendo a orientação conforme cada situação.

Infelizmente, muitos usuários acabam não respondendo às orientações. Nessas situações é preciso verificar se é possível corrigir o problema sem a intervenção do autor. Caso não o seja, a suspensão ou remoção do conteúdo pode ser necessária.

> 3. Qual é o período de tempo que você pretende moderar diariamente?

Minha intenção é investir entre meia a uma hora por dia exclusivamente para a moderação, tais como verificar flags e orientar usuários. Isso sem incluir o tempo despendido no chat, para responder perguntas ou outras atividades.

Talvez você esteja pensando que isto é bem pouco comparado com alguns usuários que relatam gastar 2, 4 ou 6 horas no site por dia. Considere que na maioria das vezes eles contam o tempo em que estão consultando o site, no chat e não efetivamente fazendo algo de construtivo.

Além disso, hoje o site não conta com um volume muito elevado de perguntas e respostas. Não sou a favor de excesso na moderação. Se alguém começar a navegar pelo site e encontrar o nome de um moderador em todo o lugar, passará a impressão de que ele está tentando se impor perante à comunidade.

Além disso, muitos casos podem e devem ser resolvidos pela fila de análise normal do site.

Obviamente, o tempo gasto no site irá variar de acordo com a necessidade. Por exemplo, agora mesmo são 3 horas da manhã e estou acordado e correndo sem parar desde às 7 horas da manhã do dia anterior. Mas tendo a necessidade de responder ao questionário, cá estou. :)

> 4. Uma pergunta é feita e recebe algumas respostas muito boas, o *AP* sinaliza a pergunta e pede para que ela seja *excluída*, pois pode-lhe causar problemas no local onde ele estuda ou no trabalho.
>      O que você faz?

Pensando no benefício para a comunidade em primeiro lugar, faria o possível para manter o conteúdo.

Em caso de informações sigilosas eu questionaria o AP sobre quais são os dados sensíveis e o orientaria a remover somente a parte que lhe causa problemas através de uma edição. Então solicitaria à equipe da Stack Exchange para remover os dados sigilosos do histórico.

Se o problema for a não associação da conta com certo conteúdo, é possível solicitar à equipe da Stack Exchange a desassociação.

Enfim, faria o possível analisando caso a caso.

> 5. Todos os dias chegam novos usuários no site postando perguntas. Como são inexperientes, muitas destas perguntas têm problemas e acabam fechadas e/ou recebendo votos contrários. Que tipo de atitudes você costuma ou pretende tomar com novos usuários que enquanto bem-intencionados, postam perguntas de má qualidade?

A primeira atitude é acalmar os ânimos. Procuro equalizar ou neutralizar comentários negativos ou depreciativos, seja de comentários enlatados mal aplicados ou até excessos dos usuários mais antigos que perdem um pouco a paciência.

Enfim, procuro orientar o novo usuário com o maior cuidado e gentileza, fazê-lo sentir-se bem-vindo e ouvido pela comunidade, mostrando o caminho para ele obter o que precisa e ao mesmo tempo seguir as regras da comunidade.

> 6. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?

Primeiramente o chamaria para uma "conversa particular" onde tentaria da forma mais amigável e gentil possível explicar que, embora ele seja um bom profissional e usuário, que sua participação seja importante, certos tipos de comportamento não podem ser tolerados.

Se o problema persistisse, dependendo de como tudo ocorrer, posso tentar chamar a atenção novamente ou ir direto para o próximo passo, que seria notificar o usuário via a ferramenta em que os moderadores podem enviar mensagens diretamente ao usuário.

Se mesmo assim o problema persistisse, a justiça terá que ser feita. Em todos os passos iria manter os demais moderadores informados. Então, iria chamá-los para deliberar sobre a punição adequada, tal como uma possível suspensão.

> 7. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

Falaria com ele diretamente. Se nos entendêssemos, ótimo. Caso contrário manteria a decisão dele.

É uma questão de respeito que uma "autoridade" deve ter por "outra". Além disso, "guerrinhas" entre moderadores iriam minar o respeito da comunidade e questionamentos sobre todas as futuras atitudes dos moderadores. Provavelmente seria um caos no site.

> 8. Um novo usuário posta uma pergunta extremamente confusa, rapidamente fechada pela comunidade, após alguns comentários explicando a ele o problema. O usuário, furioso, reclama no Meta, dizendo que aqui tem regras demais, que somos uns babacas filhos-duma-égua, mandando todo mundo pra aquele lugar. Como você reagiria?

Pediria desculpas ao mesmo, diria que somos todos humanos, que ele precisa se acalmar e que para ele obter a melhor experiência no site, o que inclui boas respostas e ajuda de especialistas, ele precisa jogar dentro das regras.

Também faria o possível para entender a pergunta original, o que ele queria. Se possível editaria a questão e a reabriria, mostrando assim ao usuário que prezamos por ajudar não só a resolver os problemas específicos, mas também na melhor forma de se fazer isso por aqui (que também creio ser uma das melhores forma de se fazer isso online!).

> 9. Caso eleito, você pretende aumentar sua participação no Meta ou você já a considera satisfatória?
>      Caso sua resposta seja que vai aumentá-la, por favor explique por que esperar se tornar um moderador para começar a interagir com a comunidade sobre as questões que definem os rumos do site? Por que já não o fez desde sempre?
>      Caso sua resposta seja que já a considera satisfatória, por favor justifique. Se possível, com exemplos de sua participação que considera que merecem destaque.

Considero minha participação no meta hoje como equilibrada. Tenho mais facilidade para responder certos tipos de pergunta, enquanto outras deixo a cargo de outros usuários que tem maior facilidade.

Por exemplo, em geral consigo responder bem perguntas sobre fechamentos, que exijam análise ou discussão sobre o conteúdo de uma pergunta. Por outro lado, perguntas sobre detalhes das regras das medalhas e coisas do tipo são respondidas muito mais rápida e diretamente por outros usuários como o @Math e o @bfavaretto.

> 10. Qual/quais *soft skills*¹ você possui que são fundamentais para um moderador do SOPt?
>       <sup>¹*soft skills*: conjunto de atributos e/ou competências que promovem boas relações com as pessoas</sup>

Não me considero um exemplo de ser humano, mas posso citar como pontos fortes as seguintes características:

- Paciência: raramente respondo de forma rude ou veemente, procurando acalmar os ânimos ao invés de exaltá-los.
- Atenciosidade: sei ouvir as pessoas, seus argumentos, os dois lados no caso de uma discussão. Não tenho medo de mudar de opinião.
- Transparência: tenho opiniões claras e dou conta de minhas ações no site. Houve casos onde ações que tomei como moderador foram questionadas no meta. A não ser que esteja enganado (se alguém achar prova do contrário, me avise), todas essas situações foram bem explicadas e os usuários compreenderam a ação. Em outras situações os usuários me convenceram de que minha ação foi incorreta e não tive problemas em voltar atrás.
- Maturidade: o tempo e as diversas experiências de vida me ajudaram a ter uma boa visão sobre o comportamento das pessoas e suas intenções. Claro que tenho muito a aprender e sempre confirmo minhas suspeitas com outros moderadores. Mas no geral isso me permite julgar certas situações complicadas.

Answer (score 9):

## Respostas do [Jorge B.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/7210/jorge-b)

> 1. Por que você precisa dos poderes de moderador ♦ para fazer o que você propôs em sua candidatura?

A primeira resposta que me ocorreu quando vi esta pergunta foi "para nada". E é verdade para moderar o site não é preciso ter poderes de moderador ♦. É só preciso ter força de vontade e querer ajudar para manter o site limpo e com uma qualidade de excelência. Embora muitas vezes tenho a certeza que me ia dar jeito para manter o site limpo como quando, por exemplo, me deparo com comentários obsoletos que não posso limpar, então sinalizo.

Acho também que poderia dar o meu contributo a passar as ideias de todos vós para a SE, sendo moderador e tendo acesso aos chats de moderadores poderia assim garantir que todos vocês estariam representados e que a vossa opinião chegaria a SE.

Acho também que daria um bom advogado do diabo, tenho um bom espirito critico e gosto sempre de ver "e se fosse assim em vez de assado".

> 2. Como você vê a qualidade das perguntas e respostas do site hoje? Enquanto moderador, como pretende atuar para manter a qualidade (se achar que está satisfatória), ou melhorá-la (se achar que isso é necessário)?

A qualidade do site está a um nível bom. Vêm-se muitas boas perguntas e muito boas respostas. Quanto a melhorar acho que poderia ser melhorada com a ajuda a novatos, que é a minha ideia principal. Ajudar na fase onde os problemas das perguntas começam, com novatos. Comentar para os ajudar. Editar a pergunta de forma a que ela se torne melhor. Um trabalho que tenho de reconhecer que o @utluiz tem feito muito bem, salvar perguntas.

Acho que há muito a fazer quanto a isso. Ajudar novatos nas suas perguntas e respostas, comentar quando preciso, e também muito importante incentivar a votar.

> 3. Qual é o período de tempo que você pretende moderar diariamente?

Diariamente passo cerca de 6/7 horas por dia no SOpt. Pretendo assim manter esse registo de atividade no site. Já diariamente faço trabalho de moderador. Estou sempre atento ao meta e ao chat, assim como a fila de analise e as perguntas que vão aparecendo.

> 4. Uma pergunta é feita e recebe algumas respostas muito boas, o *AP* sinaliza a pergunta e pede para que ela seja *excluída*, pois pode-lhe causar problemas no local onde ele estuda ou no trabalho.
>    O que você faz?

Não sei qual é a politica do site quanto a isso, mas no meu ponto de vista eu excluiria a pergunta. Se há coisa que preso é a privacidade e o respeito pelos outros. Mas claro que as politicas da SE seriam respeitadas.

> 5. Todos os dias chegam novos usuários no site postando perguntas. Como são inexperientes, muitas destas perguntas têm problemas e acabam fechadas e/ou recebendo votos contrários. Que tipo de atitudes você costuma ou pretende tomar com novos usuários que enquanto bem-intencionados, postam perguntas de má qualidade?

Como já disse na pergunta 2 essa é uma das minhas preocupações. Acho que é pelo inicio que se resolvem os problemas. Num caso desses a primeira coisa que faço é tentar perceber a pergunta e se entender o que o AP quer, alterar a pergunta para que fique melhor, se possível. Depois dar as boas vindas ao novato e encaminhá-lo para o caminho certo através de comentários. Mas sempre na perspetiva de ajudar o novato.

> 6. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?

Produzir diversas boas respostas é ótimo claro, mas é muito mais importante manter o site em ordem. Num caso destes falaria com o usuário de forma a tentar fazê-lo ver que o site é um site feito para nós e por nós, mas que o respeito e a cordialidade são a base da boa qualidade que o site mantém. Isso e a qualidade das perguntas e respostas dos usuários claro. Este é um caso que me aconteceu e a mim quando cheguei. E fui guiado para o caminho certo, eu melhor que ninguém sabe como o fazer.

> 7. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

Falaria com ele e o outro moderador para tentar chegar a um consenso. No caso de haverem dúvidas poderia ser aberta uma pergunta no meta para discussão do caso em questão. Porque a opinião de todos nós é muito importante.

> 8. Um novo usuário posta uma pergunta extremamente confusa, rapidamente fechada pela comunidade, após alguns comentários explicando a ele o problema. O usuário, furioso, reclama no Meta, dizendo que aqui tem regras demais, que somos uns babacas filhos-duma-égua, mandando todo mundo pra aquele lugar. Como você reagiria?

Primeiro de tudo eliminaria tudo que fosse ofensivo, logo de seguida tentaria elucidar o AP que o site funciona muito bem e tem uma qualidade bem acima da média por esse motivos, por ter regras e por existir respeito entre os usuários. No caso de não conseguir acalmar o usuário e ele continuasse com esse comportamento teria de falar com os outros moderadores para tomarmos uma decisão.

> 9. Caso eleito, você pretende aumentar sua participação no Meta ou você já a considera satisfatória?
>    Caso sua resposta seja que vai aumentá-la, por favor explique por que esperar se tornar um moderador para começar a interagir com a comunidade sobre as questões que definem os rumos do site? Por que já não o fez desde sempre?
>    Caso sua resposta seja que já a considera satisfatória, por favor justifique. Se possível, com exemplos de sua participação que considera que merecem destaque.

Eu sou bastante participativo no meta, todos os dias dou o meu contributo para que o site melhore a cada dia que passa. Se aumentaria a minha participação? Aumentaria com toda a certeza não por ter-me tornado moderador mas sim por ter acesso a mais informação e a um canal mais rápido para saber algumas respostas relativas ao site.

> 10. Qual/quais *soft skills*¹ você possui que são fundamentais para um moderador do SOPt?
>     <sup>¹*soft skills*: conjunto de atributos e/ou competências que promovem boas relações com as pessoas</sup>

Todos que me conhecem sabem que sou uma pessoa afável, calmo e ponderado. Adoro interagir com pessoas como se pode ver pela minha participação no [chat do SOpt](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/11910/estouro-de-pilha?tab=general). Além disso também tenho um bom espirito critico para por em causa algumas coisa que possa achar que esteja mal, mas mantendo sempre a calma e a postura para não criar atritos.

Comment: Achei sensacional a sinceridade da sua primeira resposta e ao mesmo tempo como se saiu tão bem. Tá difícil decidir meus votos :)

Answer (score 6):

## Respostas do [rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/91/rray)

> 1 - Por que você precisa dos poderes de moderador ? para fazer o que você propôs em sua candidatura?

Ter os poderes de moderador facilita na manutenção do site, como remover, fechar ou reabrir publicações, já eu não tenho todos esses privilégios.

> 2 - Como você vê a qualidade das perguntas e respostas do site hoje? Enquanto moderador, como pretende atuar para manter a qualidade (se achar que está satisfatória), 
>   ou melhorá-la (se achar que isso é necessário)?

Para manter a qualidade das publicações, ações que ajudam são editar os títulos das perguntas para facilitar a pesquina no google, tagar ela corretamente, deixa como comentário ou incluir em uma resposta links de perguntas sobre assuntos complementares ou relacionados e claro editar o texto da publicação quando necessário.

> 3 - Qual é o período de tempo que você pretende moderar diariamente?

Acesso o site enquanto estou acordado, se fosse definir um horário seria das 7:00 - 7:30 am até a 1:00 am, nesse
periódo verifico as filas de analises, perguntas do site e geralmente estou no chat basta chamar :).

> 4 - Uma pergunta é feita e recebe algumas respostas muito boas, o AP sinaliza a pergunta e pede para que ela seja excluída, pois pode-lhe causar problemas no local onde ele estuda ou no trabalho.
>   O que você faz?

No caso da pergunta se tornar popular e atrair muitas visualizações, o que deve ser feito é solicitar que o autor crie uma nova pergunta descaracterizando as

informações sensiveis ou proprio moderador criar uma nova como cw, recortar as repostas da pergunta antiga, colar na nova e finalmente apagar a antiga. Ela deve ser excluida para não exibir o histórico.

> 5 - Todos os dias chegam novos usuários no site postando perguntas. Como são inexperientes, muitas destas perguntas têm problemas e acabam fechadas e/ou recebendo

votos contrários. Que tipo de atitudes você costuma ou pretende tomar com novos usuários que enquanto bem-intencionados, postam perguntas de má qualidade?

O que faço hoje é indicar o link da tour para ele se familiarizar com com a interface do site também indico o link de como perguntar (central de ajuda). Através dos comentários tento obter mais detalhes do problema isso ajuda de duas formas a primeira é fazer o autor entender melhor o problema e descreve-lo de forma simples para todos e também para um possível edição da pergunta.

A primeira vez que usei um Q&A (não foi o SO) foi pessima, conhecia o stackoverflow me parecia um fórum mais organizado, ainda não tinha conta e não sabia como era o modelo e as unidades basicas(pergunta, resposta e comentário). Fiz um comentário para ajudar no espaço de uma resposta, haha minha reputação foi para -6 (como se isso não fosse ruim não pode excluir minha 'resposta' :D) recebi uns comentários que deveria fazer um 'resposta' e nenhum link explicando o porque. Não desisti de ajudar os outros aprendi o como funciona o modelo e continuei a contribuir para aquele site, logo depois migrei para o sopt, então entendo bem os usuários novos, sempre enfatizo para eles sobre os espaços da publicação e para que cada um serve.

> 6 - Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?

Cada situção pede uma ação diferente, o primeiro passo seria orientar o usuário explicar pq isso ou aquilo causa problema e quais são as consequencias para a

comunidade. Agora se o perfil do usuário for de uma pessoa que gostar de fazer tudo ao seu gosto, conversar/orientar não vai servir de muita coisa, o que pode

acontecer é o usuário deixar a comunidade. Essa pergunta me parece um caso **bem** real, que aconteceu no sopt.

> 7 - Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

Isso é normal não é possível ter um consenso o tempo todo, primeiro conversaria com o moderador pediria mais detalhes sobre a ação, tentaria entender o que levou ele a fazer isso já que eu não penso da mesma forma e não tenho as mesmas ideias e também tentarei explicar o meu ponto de vista.

> 8 - Um novo usuário posta uma pergunta extremamente confusa, rapidamente fechada pela comunidade, após alguns comentários explicando a ele o problema. O usuário,

furioso, reclama no Meta, dizendo que aqui tem regras demais, que somos uns babacas filhos-duma-égua, mandando todo mundo pra aquele lugar. Como você reagiria?

A principio explicaria as regras mais basicas do site, depois eu a comunidade tentarimos ajudar ele a eleborar melhor a pergunta. Quanto a questão de site ter ou não

muitas regras não isso como um problema no mundo real temos uma serie de restrições que não gostamos mas temos que fazer, por exemplo teime com o guardo banco (não o

de dados xD) em passar com algo de metal ou mocilha para ver o que acontece, goste ou não regras devem ser respeitas em alguns casos quando possível procure por um

'serviço' mais adequado a você.

> 9 - Caso eleito, você pretende aumentar sua participação no Meta ou você já a considera satisfatória?
>   Caso sua resposta seja que vai aumentá-la, por favor explique por que esperar se tornar um moderador para começar a interagir com a comunidade sobre as questões que definem os rumos do site? Por que já não o fez desde sempre?
>   Caso sua resposta seja que já a considera satisfatória, por favor justifique. Se possível, com exemplos de sua partipação que considera que merecem destaque.

O moderador tem praticamento obrigatoriedade de fazer publicações no meta, seja para tirar uma simples dúvida ou para orientar a comunidade sobre determinado tema/comportamento.

Minha participação hoje é moderada o meta também é de épocas, umas mais agitadas outras paradas, gosto de adicionar minha contribuição sobre vários temas, os principais são: como ajudar iniciantes a entender o modelo, como elaborar um boa pergunta, o que mais gostei foi de ter iniciado a [tradução de um sessão do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2231/91), após poucos minutos, alguns usuários do site editaram a publicação adicionando correções e melhorias ao texto, o que mostra que a comunidade é bem unida mesmo.

> 10 - Qual/quais soft skills¹ você possui que são fundamentais para um moderador do SOPt?
>   ¹soft skills: conjunto de atributos e/ou competências que promovem boas relações com as pessoas

Paciência, proatividade para ajudar os usuários, ter boas habilidades de advinhação, ser firme em algumas situações, ter empatia.

Comment: Me desculpem pela demora :)

Comment: Dê uma revisada nas quebras de parágrafos. Há várias que bagunçam um pouco a estrutura do texto.

Comment: Acho que você esqueceu de responder a questão 9. Dá uma editada aí. ;)

Comment: Você dorme muito pouco :)

Comment: @bfavaretto mto pouco :( as vezes até menos

Comment: @VictorStafusa, editei a resposta, respondi a 9 e :P coloquei espaço depois do parenteses hehe.

Answer (score 4):

## Respostas do [patrick-maciel](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/85/patrick-maciel)

> 1. Por que você precisa dos poderes de moderador ♦ para fazer o que você propôs em sua candidatura?

Apesar das minhas boas intenções e vontade de fazer o SOPt ser uma comunidade melhor, mais ativa e com uma excelente qualidade, nem sempre tenho o "poder" suficiente para questionar algo, por exemplo:

- Analisar melhor algo mal visto pelos usuários
- Buscar soluções para problemas comuns
- Orientar novos usuários em ocmo obter mais respostas e realizar boas perguntas
- Participar de maneiras mais ativa (como usuário tenho uma meta, como moderador outras)
- Resolver de maneira mais rápida discussões desnecessárias

E claro, sei que eu além de outros usuários tem várias idéias de como melhorar a comunidade/sistema como um todo. Pretendo participar disso se tiver oportunidade para fazer com que o SOPt tenha uma boa imagem interna e externamente.

> 2. Como você vê a qualidade das perguntas e respostas do site hoje? Enquanto moderador, como pretende atuar para manter a qualidade (se achar que está satisfatória), ou melhorá-la (se achar que isso é necessário)?

Sinceramente a qualidade não está tão boa. Falta padrão, pesquisar antes, detalhes, e o simples fato de entender que quem vai ajudar o usuário que postou é outro usuário sem um conhecimento detalhado do problema do outro.

Como sugestão de melhoria, não acho que simplesmente sinalizar e/ou fechar as perguntas mal realizadas seja a solução para todos os problemas. Ajuda um pouco fazer isso? Sem dúvida! Afinal de contas pelo menos com isso evitamos perguntas mal elaboradas, porém ainda sim não ensinamos nada com isso e nada vai mudar, ou seja: entramos em um círculo vicioso.

Pretendo mesmo que através de comentários na perguntas e/ou entrando em contato diretamente com o usuário, dar dicas de como ele pode melhorar as suas perguntas, além disso acho extremamente viável procurarmos adotar um padrão de questão e/ou algum modelo (que seja durante a criação da pergunta, um post, um link externo, um link no layout de criação da pergunta, um "esqueleto" de como deve ser a questão, um tutorial, etc. Tenho várias idéias mas não sei até onde o SO está disposto a ir para investir nelas).

Prezo muito pela qualidade das questões e respostas do SOPt, assim como tenho enorme interesse em agregar conhecimento aos usuários.

> 3. Qual é o período de tempo que você pretende moderar diariamente?

Trabalho em horário comercial, porém estou conectado 24hrs por dia. Não tenho problemas em ficar logado no SOPt exercendo a minha obrigação sempre que houver tempo livre.

Fora isso, após as 17:30h estou livre e com todo prazer estarei disponível para ajudar a comunidade com o que for necessário.

Não garanto é claro que estarei constantemente logado e/ou que minhas respostas e análises serão a cada minuto, mas sempre que possível estarei por aqui e com certeza vou realizar meu trabalho com excelência.

> 4. Uma pergunta é feita e recebe algumas respostas muito boas, o AP sinaliza a pergunta e pede para que ela seja excluída, pois pode-lhe causar problemas no local onde ele estuda ou no trabalho. O que você faz?

Talvez uma mera edição na questão para deixá-la mais genérica e com o mínimo de detalhes possíveis realizados ao usuário (seu trabalho/função/projeto) seja o suficiente, mas logicamente cabe a mim e aos demais moderadores entender melhor qual questionamento, afinal de contas, queremos apenas solucionar problemas e não causar.

> 5. Todos os dias chegam novos usuários no site postando perguntas. Como são inexperientes, muitas destas perguntas têm problemas e acabam fechadas e/ou recebendo votos contrários. Que tipo de atitudes você costuma ou pretende tomar com novos usuários que enquanto bem intencionados, postam perguntas de má qualidade?

Esse é um dos sérios problemas do SO. De forma alguma um usuário novo tem condição de chegar aqui já entendendo como deve ser feito a pergunta e com a melhor forma de descrever seu problema, porém os usuários mais experientes (ou não), dão votos negativos a questão sem antes mesmo tentar editá-la e fazer comentários e/ou críticas positivas.

Pretendo é claro, além de editar a pergunta para que ela tenha uma qualidade melhor, solicitar do usuário mais informações a respeito do questão, orientando-o a postar a maior quantidade de detalhes possíveis e para isso, creio de uma das soluções seria um post/link/página aqui com modelos de perguntas e respostas, além de claro, de uma explicação mais detalhada do porque invesitr alguns minutos a mais para postar algo de qualidade ao invés de simplesmente dizer "não funciona".

> 6. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?

Certamente entrarei em contato com ele por e-mail inicialmente, buscando uma solução para esta situação, é claro, parabenizando ele pelas boas respostas e tempo investido no SOPt.

Porém para fazer isso, precisarei realizar uma melhor análise, pois é uma situação bastante delicada questionar alguém que apesar de ter boas respostas, não saber manter "a paz na comunidade".

Portanto irei analisar com cautela a situação para buscar uma melhor maneira de tocar neste assunto de uma maneira que eu consiga solucionar o problema sem afastar este usuário do SOPt.

> 7. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

Entraria em contato com ele para saber quais foram suas justificativas quanto a esse fechamento.

De qualquer forma, tenho certeza que os moderadores tem bom senso e conhecimento o suficiente para julgar algo, afinal de contas, durante a eleição que estamos agora tem perguntas o suficiente para descobrir a personalidade de cada um.

> 8. Um novo usuário posta uma pergunta extremamente confusa, rapidamente fechada pela comunidade, após alguns comentários explicando a ele o problema. O usuário, furioso, reclama no Meta, dizendo que aqui tem regras demais, que somos uns babacas filhos-duma-égua, mandando todo mundo pra aquele lugar. Como você reagiria?

Logicamente iria questionar inicialmente o porque da falta de educação, afinal de contas, nada é resolvido desta maneira.

Após isso certamente eu iria lhe perguntar sobre sua pergunta, a quantidade de detalhes que ele forneceu e/ou pode fornecer, e claro, orientá-lo a realizar uma nova pergunta, se possível naquele exato momento e com a minha supervisão para ajudá-lo a resolver o seu problema.

> 9. Caso eleito, você pretende aumentar sua participação no Meta ou você já a considera satisfatória?
>      Caso sua resposta seja que vai aumentá-la, por favor explique por que esperar se tornar um moderador para começar a interagir com a comunidade sobre as questões que definem os rumos do site? Por que já não o fez desde sempre?
>      Caso sua resposta seja que já a considera satisfatória, por favor justifique. Se possível, com exemplos de sua participação que considera que merecem destaque.

Considero aumentar pois realmente não tenho participado muito.

Sou uma pessoa que sempre coloca "metas" para cumprir durante cada ano da minha vida, até então, eu não havia decidido ser mais participativo no Meta, porém agora decidi ser moderador e obviamente considero participar o máximpo possível para fazer do meu tempo aqui o mais proveitoso para todos, além da excelente experiência que irei ter em poder ajudar uma comunidade brasileira a crescer e ter uma maior qualidade perante as demais.

Desde sempre apenas busquei melhorar as questões e respostas, e claro ajudar os usuários com suas dúvidas. Esta até então foi minha meta.

Agora estou em outro cenário e com isso, novas obrigações e responsabilidades, e assim como um trabalho normal, pretendo exercer com excelência em todas as áreas possíveis, seja avaliando, editando, comentando, participando do meta e/ou quaisquer outros pontos que visam ajuda a comunidade como um todo.

> 10. Qual/quais soft skills¹ você possui que são fundamentais para um moderador do SOPt?

- Extremamente educado: a base de tudo
- Bom senso
- Empatia
- Excelente conhecimento técnico e em análise (visando que boa parte das pessoas aqui são usuários técnicos, saber conversar tecnicamente e entender do que você está falando, ajuda e muito a convivência)
- Experiência em treinamentos e pequenas lideranças

Comment: Falta-te a pergunta 1 e tens a 8 repartida em 3 e pode criar confusão. Podias fazer 8.1, 8.2 e 8.3 para melhorar a percepção.

Comment: @JorgeB. Obrigado meu amigo. Realmente no momento de copiar as questões deixei uma pra trás, e divide o restante pra ficar mais claro a resposta, porém fugi do padrão do pessoal. Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Por que você precisa dos poderes de moderador ♦ para fazer o que você propôs em sua candidatura?

Mesmo estando como membro comum, com o crescimento de minha pontuação eu posso fazer um excelente trabalho de moderação. E sem dúvida algumas tarefas evitam certos constrangimentos quando feitas como moderador.

Sem contar que sendo uma eleição democrática, estou recebendo da comunidade a autoridade para agir em nome dela e assim representa-la nas decisões.

> 2. Como você vê a qualidade das perguntas e respostas do site hoje? Enquanto moderador, como pretende atuar para manter a qualidade (se achar que está satisfatória), ou melhorá-la (se achar que isso é necessário)?

Acredito que a qualidade de site como o SOpt ou qualquer outro de natureza colaborativa, está diretamente ligado as intenções dos membros em especial os mais ativos. Portanto o ato de moderar e dedicar a manutenção das perguntas, e alertas do usuário será á forma mais eficiente que vejo para manter ou melhorar o site.

> 3. Qual é o período de tempo que você pretende moderar diariamente?

No máximo uma hora inicialmente, percebendo que será preciso mais tempo, procurarei ajustar a carência em horas extras em dias onde eu esteja profissionalmente mais sossegado.

> 4. Uma pergunta é feita e recebe algumas respostas muito boas, o AP sinaliza a pergunta e pede para que ela seja excluída, pois pode-lhe causar problemas no local onde ele estuda ou no trabalho.
>      O que você faz?

É uma situação bastante delicada, caso a pergunta seja muito importante para o site, e eu perceba que seu conteúdo possa ser reaproveitado sem expor o AP, irei solicitar autorização para refaze-la e posta-la novamente no site de forma que todos possam ser beneficiados.

Porém é importante lembrar da atual política de licença de conteúdo do site.

Mas de forma alguma irei expor qualquer participante no site a situações delicadas, mas sempre procurarei orienta-lo a aproveitar o site da melhor forma.

> 5. Todos os dias chegam novos usuários no site postando perguntas. Como são inexperientes, muitas destas perguntas têm problemas e acabam fechadas e/ou recebendo votos contrários. Que tipo de atitudes você costuma ou pretende tomar com novos usuários que enquanto bem-intencionados, postam perguntas de má qualidade?

Sempre orienta-los, mesmo sem ser moderador já tenho feito isso quando tenho conhecimento do tema, quando não mas posso contribuir de alguma forma, assim o faço.

> 6. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?

Eu o orientaria a abrir um chat para o tema, se eu mesmo não o fizer com base nos comentários.

> 7. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

Conversaria com ele e buscaria um consenso.

> 8. Um novo usuário posta uma pergunta extremamente confusa, rapidamente fechada pela comunidade, após alguns comentários explicando a ele o problema. O usuário, furioso, reclama no Meta, dizendo que aqui tem regras demais, que somos uns babacas filhos-duma-égua, mandando todo mundo pra aquele lugar. Como você reagiria?

Mais uma vez iria orientar, caso o usuário insista com a conduta inadequada, sem dúvida agirei conforme as regras do site para a conduta em questão.

> 9. Caso eleito, você pretende aumentar sua participação no Meta ou você já a considera satisfatória?
>      Caso sua resposta seja que vai aumentá-la, por favor explique por que esperar se tornar um moderador para começar a interagir com a comunidade sobre as questões que definem os rumos do site? Por que já não o fez desde sempre?
>      Caso sua resposta seja que já a considera satisfatória, por favor justifique. Se possível, com exemplos de sua participação que considera que merecem destaque.

Bem, quando e se eleito irei analisar a necessidade de aumentar meu tempo no site, inicialmente a proposta que faço de uma hora por dia, acredito ser suficiente, com uma dedicação maior quando explicitamente necessário, se não o fiz antes, foi porque não tinha percebido o valor do site, e tenho cada vez e sempre que posso dedicado me dedicado mais um pouco.

Posso dizer que hoje, nem que seja para ler perguntas visito o site, mesmo que não tenho duvida alguma, e mesmo estando sobrecarregado com meus próprios projetos.

Portanto, neste ano de 2015, estou adotando o SOpt como um de meus projetos profissionais e pessoais.

> 10. Qual/quais soft skills¹ você possui que são fundamentais para um moderador do SOPt?

- Eu me considero bastante justo, não costumo tomar decisões sem antes avaliar as opiniões envolvidas.
- Sou muito dedicado aos meus projetos, e sempre busco desenvolver e me aprofundar tecnicamente no trabalho envolvido, o que pode contribuir para minha atuação como Moderador.
- Adoro ensinar para quem quer Aprender
- Voluntário por natureza.